# Current week in org agenda (starting today and ending next Sunday)

Tags: org-agenda

I want my agenda to show the current week starting from today until the end of the week, Sunday. How do I go about achieving this?

The code

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(("w" "Current week"
                                  (agenda "" ((org-agenda-span 'week)
                                              (org-agenda-start-day "-0d")
                                              (org-agenda-start-on-weekday 1))))))
```

Shows the current week starting from Monday rather than the current day, if I set 
`org-agenda-start-on-weekday` to `nil` then the agenda shows until next Tuesday (if today is Tuesday for example).

NOTE: I can compute the number of days from today until next Monday (though I am not 100% sure how to do it in elisp) and set `org-agenda-span` accordingly, but I don't think I can do it as part of `org-agenda-custom-commands`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done easily if you can compute the days between today and next sunday, something you said you already achieved, which can be done in several ways and I find to be the trickiest part.

Adding this to your custom agenda definitions (and re-evaluating it) will do it:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("s" "From today to next sunday"
      ((agenda ""
           ((org-agenda-start-on-weekday nil)
            (org-agenda-span (my/days-to-next-sunday))))))
         )
  ;; ... other commands here
)
```

`my/days-to-next-sunday` should return the number of days between today and next Sunday you want to include in the agenda, I do assume that you want today included, so there is no need to look back 1 day in custom command definition.

Key `s` to call it from the agenda menu can be changed to anything you like.

---

As an aside example, taking the bare-bones, lazy (*and not* the better/proper) lane, given that `(format-time-string "%u")` will return the current day of week, and those run from 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday) this will return the number of days in between today and Sunday, today included. Please, spare any possible dumb bug, it's untested code just to show the idea.

```lisp
(defun my/days-to-next-sunday()
  (let ((dayspan 0)
        (today (string-to-number (format-time-string "%u"))))
    (cond
      ((> today 0)
        ; from today till sunday, today included
        (setq dayspan (- 8 today))) 
      ((= today 0)
        ; sunday to sunday
        (setq dayspan 8)))))
```

Probably I'd rely on calc or system `date` to find the dayspan if I were to write a more reusable way to find intervals, but it'll make the example harder to understand.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that a function would be evaluated when the agenda is shown (I didn't notice the quote in my own code). I ended up simply setting `org-agenda-span` to `(- 8  (string-to-number (format-time-string "%u")))`